# Laravel pass model class as paramter in function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have written a Controller which delete a record from the database, which is pretty straight forward. The code look like below.

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            MyModel::where('id', json_decode($request->get('data'),true)['id'])->delete();
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Deleted successfully'
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong!!', 'exception_message' => $e]);
        }
    }
```

Now i wish to use the logic of delete at one common place, there will be many model which will have destroy function. So I wrote this

```
public function destroy(Request $request)
    {
        return Crud::destroy(MyModel::class, $request);
    }
```

**Crud Class**

```
<?php


namespace App\Helper;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class Crud extends Controller
{

    public static function destroy(Model $model,Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $output = $model::where('id', $request->get('id'))->delete();
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Deleted successfully',
                'output' => $output
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => 'Something went wrong!!', 'exception_message' => $e]);
        }
    }

}

?>
```

But when i call destroy function i am getting error as `Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Helper\Crud::destroy() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given,`

How can i pass Laravel Model in a function.

Comment: You need to pass it an instance of a model (for example result of `Model::first()`, will return an instance). `Model::class` will return full namespaced path of the model (string).

Comment: how can i do that in above example. I am unable to do it.

Comment: That's up to you to figure out. From the posted code, it's impossible to tell how you're using the function and what your desired result is

Comment: @devk i am creating a generic controller which will handle all my crud operations. First function is working fine but it is only for one specific module. I do not wish to implement the same delete logic again and again, because of only change being name of Model on which delete is called.

Comment: change `destroy(Model $model,Request $request)` to `destroy($model,Request $request)` and it should be fine. the model Model doesn't exist. Using string as models work, just don't hint it.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I have tried that option it doesn't throw error in this case and also does nothing.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey Sorry I just something inside of function because which destroy didn't worked. It worked now. Thanks!!!

Comment: Good. You can go on now. Happy coding. I'll add the answer below. I had this problem once myself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change

```
public static function destroy(Model $model,Request $request)
{ ... }
```

to

```
public static function destroy($model,Request $request)
{ ... }
```

The model `Model` doesn't exist as an instance. Using a string as a model works, just don't hint it.

Answer (score 0):

**At the time of function define write like that**

```
public function destroy($id, Model $model){
    $data = $model::find($id);
    if($data){
        $data->delete();
        return response()->json([
                'status' => 'success',
                'message' => 'Deleted successfully'
            ]);
    }else{
        return response()->json([
                'status' => 'failed',
                'message' => 'Data not found'
            ]);
    }
}
```

**At the time of function call write like that**

```
$this->destroy(5, Video::class);
```

*Use `$this` if function is defined in the same class*